# A synonym for "to make someone mess something up"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, grammar, american-english

> If someone is making something and you start talking to him and because of this, he loses his focus and becomes unsuccessful in making that, how do you state that in spoken American English? Is this right?:
>
> I made him mess making that up!

I know that "I messed him up" has a different meaning.

Is there any better way to state that?

Answer (score 1):

> You [**distracted**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/distract) him, so he wasn't paying attention to his work and started making mistakes.

You could say:

> You made him **mess up**.

but I would consider it informal usage.